# How to filter columns when adding data into MS Access using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an excel file with two sheets. The first one I want to add the entire sheet to an MS Access table - and so far this code is accomplishing that. But with the second sheet (sheet2) I want to be able to filter the columns and create two tables from that sheet. So I'd like to make the first table range from columns A1:B1,E1:F1 and include any data that is in the rows below it. Then for the other table I'd like the columns to be C1:D1.

Here is my code that I have embedded into an import button on an Access form:

```
Private Sub btnImportSpreadsheet_Click()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    
    If FSO.FileExists(Nz(Me.txtFileName, "")) Then
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Sheet1", _
            Me.txtFileName, True, "Sheet1!"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Sheet2", _
            Me.txtFileName, True, "Sheet2!"
    Else
        MsgBox "File not found"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Upon clicking import this creates two tables inside Access, sheet1 and sheet2.

What I've tried to do is filter it by adding in A1:B1,E1:F1 into the Range area (where Sheet2! is) like so:

```
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Sheet2", _
        Me.txtFileName, True, "A1:B1,E1:F1"
```

But when I run that code it tells me that: "The Microsoft Access engine could not find the object "A1:B1,E1:F1" - I think it doesn't allow multi-ranges like this.

The other issue is that when I just use "A1:B1" that only gives me back the columns, and none of the data in the rows below it.

How can I create two tables from Sheet2 with the first being A1:B1,E1:F1 and the second table being C1:D1?

Thank you

**Edit:** with the help of June7 the solution to this is to add a currentDb() and then from that execute an SQL query that removes a specific field name:

```
If FSO.FileExists(Nz(Me.txtFileName, "")) Then
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Sheet2", _
        Me.txtFileName, True, "Sheet2!"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Sheet3", _
        Me.txtFileName, True, "Sheet3!"

Set dbs = CurrentDb()
dbs.Execute "ALTER TABLE Sheet3 DROP COLUMN a_field_name"

Else
    MsgBox "File not found"
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Could import entire range, copy table, remove unneeded fields from each.

Comment: @June7 thanks for the reply. I need to run this 1000s of times, so it can't just be a one-off kind of thing. Ill need to it do the filtering automatically.

Comment: @June7 I think I understand better what you said. Are you saying I could copy the entire range then delete the unneeded fields all with the VBA before it ever makes it way to the Access tables?

Comment: Well, fields and data would be in the new tables and then just remove. Removing fields can be automated. Use SQL ALTER TABLE if you know the specific field names. Or use DAO TableDefs and can reference fields by index identifier - columns C1:D1 would be indexes 2 and 3. Right now I don't see any easier way around the multi-range dataset.

Comment: @June7 this SQL, would it be nested inside the VBA? Can you give an example of this?

Comment: `CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP COLUMN FieldName1, FieldName2"`.

Comment: @June7 Thanks that works! I updated my question. Is there any way to instead select a column range in the SQL query, so instead of listing each table name, could I just remove columns 3-7?

Comment: Did you mean "each **field** name"? My suggestion is to DROP fields, not table. No, query cannot work that way. That is why I suggested DAO TableDefs as alternative. I am exploring that code now. Columns 3-7 - I thought there were only 2 columns for removal?

Comment: @June7 thank you, updated to reflect "field" not "table". Any column range would do, just need a general way to remove column ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the full worksheet then modify table. Options:

1. If resulting field names are known, import full range to Table1 then use SQL action statements:

   ```vb
   'to create new Table2
   CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT Field3, Field4 INTO Table2 FROM Table1"

   'or to add records to established Table2
   CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table2(Field3, Field4) SELECT Field3, Field4 FROM Table1" 

   'then to remove fields from Table1
   CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP COLUMN Field3, Field4"
   ```
2. If field names are unknown, import full range to Table1 and range C:D to Table2. Then Use DAO TableDefs to remove unneeded fields from Table1 - remove higher index first.

   ```vb
   For x = 3 to 2 Step -1
        CurrentDb.TableDefs("Table1").Fields.Delete _
                  CurrentDb.TableDefs("Table1").Fields(x).Name
   Next
   ```

   or just delete field index 2 in each iteration because deleting lower first causes fields to shift down one index

   ```vb
   For x = 2 to 3
        CurrentDb.TableDefs("Table1").Fields.Delete _
                  CurrentDb.TableDefs("Table1").Fields(2).Name
   Next
   ```

With either method, perhaps loop through all 1,000 workbooks to import each into Table1 then outside loop do table modifications. Depends how many records are involved and if memory can handle the SQL. Otherwise, import into a 'temp' table and move data to permanent tables with `INSERT INTO SELECT` action within loop. Either delete records from 'temp' table before each import or drop table and create with each import.

Comment: Thank you! What does the ````For x = 2 to 3```` do exactly? Is this like saying only use columns ranging from 2 to 3 inside the sheet? when I run this code I am told 'x' is undefined.

Comment: Yes, that is referring to field by index position in table design. Index is 0-based so first field is index 0. Should probably declare the x variable: `Dim x As Integer`.

Comment: When I run this it remove the column's C and E, and everything else remains.

Comment: Where is column D?

Comment: D and F are added to the table.

Comment: I am confused. The code removes sequential fields. How would it skip D and go to E?

Comment: Here is a link to the MS Access db and the excel file: https://postimg.cc/N50dTLJj

Comment: Those are just images that could have been embedded within your question. Does not clarify. If you want to provide database and workbook, suggest posting in a forum that allows attaching files.

Comment: You're right. The first method is fine I know the field names. I can add to the table once with the removed columns just fine. But when I try to import the file a second time it tells me it cant import it because it doesn't have that field name. Is there any way around this?

Comment: So subsequent imports would be adding records to existing table(s)? That really changes things. These imports are all new records - not updating data, not cumulative? I think you will need to import to a 'temp' table then 'move' records to existing permanent table(s) with SQL (explore INSERT SELECT). So even before first import, will have to establish table(s). Are Table1 and Table2 supposed to have a relationship? Or why have two tables?

Comment: I have 1000 excel files which all share the same column names. The sheet that Table1 and Table2 are derived from share the same Country name but the information inside the sheet columns needs to be divided into two separate tables. Would the steps for solving the multiple import issue be to have a temp table inside the DB that holds the original un-truncated excel file and its schema, then I would truncate that one and add the result to a final table?

Comment: Yes, that was what my last comment indicated. But again, why two tables? Queries can specify which fields to retrieve and be used like a table.

Comment: I figured out why the TableDefs code fails. Because deleting Field3 causes Field4 to become index 2 instead of index 3. Need to delete the higher index first or just repeatedly delete index 2. Revised code.